# Risky Using Forever + Sudo to keep node app running?

Tags: node.js, sudo, forever

Is it risky to keep a node.js application running as sudo using forever.js? What potential problems are there? If this is ill-advised what is a better alternative?

Comment: Upvoted because I want to know the answer too. In my case forever dies after a couple of days and I've dealt with it using a cronjob to stop and restart all daily. Not elegant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running an app via `sudo` is indeed highly risky. Your app will have full root privileges meaning the number of possible attacks and severity of possible attacks is significantly higher than if you ran your application as a dedicated user for this application. I strongly recommend following the industry best practices here and running your application as a normal non-root user.

As to `forever` this category of software is generally called "process supervision" and there are many non-risky options available. I personally use the process supervision system built into my deployment OS, which is currently `upstart` or `systemd`, but I think `forever` is one of several alternatives that are perfectly fine. I recommend [Process Supervision: Solved Problem](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2012/12/29/process-supervision-solved-problem/) as a good overview of process supervision with some good insights.

Comment: Thanks. It's as I feared. Could you provide some references/further resources on the best practices you recommend.